# Flag randomly selected N rows by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

At the data.table in column C3 I want to flag N randomly selected rows by each group (C1). There are several similar questions have already been asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999215/how-to-randomly-choose-only-one-row-in-each-group?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887083/from-data-table-randomly-select-one-row-per-group) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289182/sample-random-rows-within-each-group-in-a-data-table). But based on the answers still cannot figure out how to find a solution for my task.

```
set.seed(1)    
dt = data.table(C1 = c("A","A","A","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"), 
                 C2 = c(2,1,3,1,2,3,4,5,4,5)) 

dt
    C1 C2
 1:  A  2
 2:  A  1
 3:  A  3
 4:  B  1
 5:  C  2
 6:  C  3
 7:  C  4
 8:  D  5
 9:  D  4
10:  D  5
```

Here are row indexes for two randomly selected rows by each group C1 (doesn't work well for group B):

```
dt[, sample(.I, min(.N, 2)), by = C1]$V1
[1]  1  3  3  7  5 10  9
```

*NB: for B only one row should be selected because group B consists of one row only.*

Here is a solution for one randomly selected row in each group, which often doesn't work for group B:

```
dt[, C3 := .I == sample(.I, 1), by = C1]
dt
    C1 C2    C3
 1:  A  2 FALSE
 2:  A  1  TRUE
 3:  A  3 FALSE
 4:  B  1 FALSE
 5:  C  2  TRUE
 6:  C  3 FALSE
 7:  C  4 FALSE
 8:  D  5  TRUE
 9:  D  4 FALSE
10:  D  5 FALSE
```

Actually I want to expand it on N rows. I've tried (for two rows):

```
dt[, C3 := .I==sample(.I, min(.N, 2)), by = C1]
```

which of course doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt[, C3 := 1:.N %in% sample(.N, min(.N, 2)), by = C1]
```

Or use `head`, but I think that should be slower

```
dt[, C3 := 1:.N %in% head(sample(.N), 2) , by = C1]
```

If the number of flagged rows is not constant you can do

```
flagsz <- c(2, 1, 2, 3)
dt[, C3 := 1:.N %in% sample(.N, min(.N, flagsz[.GRP])), by = C1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Just to understand: we check all rows if they were sampled and those which were sampled receives TRUE, right?

Comment: Yes. `1:.N` gives the in-group row-number, and if the row-number is in the sample of those row numbers `sample(.N, min(.N, 2))` then `C3` is `TRUE`

Comment: I wonder what if the number of items to flag is different for each group C1? Suppose N = c(2, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Ryan!

Answer (score 1):

```
N=2
dt[, C3 := {if (.N < N) rep(TRUE,.N) else 1:.N %in%  sample(.N,N) }, by=C1]
dt
# C1 C2    C3
# 1:  A  2  TRUE
# 2:  A  1 FALSE
# 3:  A  3  TRUE
# 4:  B  1  TRUE
# 5:  C  2 FALSE
# 6:  C  3  TRUE
# 7:  C  4  TRUE
# 8:  D  5  TRUE
# 9:  D  4  TRUE
# 10:  D  5 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! You answer works just fine. I have accepted Ryan's answer because his answer doesn't consist of if-else.